# Why is my list element is recalled as str when compared with another int in a for cycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

I have a txt source which consists of 3 numbers (with the maximum value of 30)and an enter at the end of each line. My goal is to make this source file into a list (2-dimensional array) in python, then be able to tell what is the minimum of the first number from any line's first number.

The conversion of the source file is the following so far:

```
list=[]
f=open("tavok.txt")
for sor in f:
    if sor[-1]=='\n':sor = sor[:-1]
    sor = sor.split()
    sor = [int(x) for x in sor]
    list.append(sor)
print(list)
```

This gives us a list with lists inside with 3 elements, all of them being integers. Then, I try to compare the first element of each list inside if it is smaller than the current minimum. (100 is just a value to exceed the 30 limit of the numbers)

```
minimum=100
for x in list:
    if int(list[x][0])< minimum:
        minimum = list[x][0]
print (minimum)
```

This gives me this error message:

> "if int(list[x][0])< mini: TypeError: list indices must be integers or
>   slices, not list"

I'm new to programming and I can't find why my values are getting converted back to `str` from `int`, thus the program can't compare them and giving me this error message. Thanks for your help

Comment: Python `for` loop is a for each loop, as it directly iterates through values and not indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `x` is a list, so you can't use it to index another list.

```
if int(x[0])< minimum
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I must note that using `list` as variable name is bad idea, as it is keyword of Python langauge. You can't use `list` function, after you use `list` as variable name.

If you want minimum value in described situation, consider following example:

```
data = [[9,3,4],[1,9,7],[4,1,2]]
minimum = min([i[0] for i in data])
print(minimum) #prints 1
```

It uses list comprehension for getting first element of each sublist and built-in `min` function. Note that this avoid magic number (`100` in your example).